# Which database table contains the Sitecore item path?

Tags: sitecore-api

I thought of query the Sitecore master/web database and get the item path information to display it in dashboard instead reading the data from Sitecore content editor.

Could I get some thoughts on here?

Comment: Entirely unclear what you're asking

Comment: Either way - never go direct to the database. Use the API to get the any information about an item you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to see the full path of Items. The function can be used in stored procedures or ad-hoc queries for reporting purposes.

```
USE [Sitecore_Master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetItemPath]
(
    @ParentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @CurrentPath VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewParentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @EmptyGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    SELECT @EmptyGUID = CAST(CAST(0 AS BINARY) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
    SELECT @CurrentPath = '/' + i.Name + @CurrentPath,
        @NewParentID = i.ParentID
    FROM Items AS i
    WHERE i.ID = @ParentID
    if(@NewParentID != @EmptyGUID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CurrentPath = dbo.GetItemPath(@NewParentID, @CurrentPath)
    END
    RETURN @CurrentPath
END
```

Here’s an example of the function in use:

```
SELECT i.ID, i.Name, dbo.GetItemPath(i.ID, '') AS FullPath
FROM Items AS i
```

Reference: [SQL Querying Sitecore Database Directly: Get FullPath of Item](https://blogs.perficient.com/2014/05/28/sql-querying-sitecore-database-directly-get-fullpath-of-item/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you see the table called "**[Items]**" in your master or web database, you will find that when the item is created you will get its ID in the ID field and parent in the ParentId field.

So if you want to get the item path, you can get the parent item ID and go to the home item.

Here is the table snippet.

[image]

Same like if you want to go to the parent of an item till home item. This way you can create the path.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore item path is not something that is really stored in any database. It's the position of the database really.

If your item is in Sitecore content tree under "sitecore" -> "content" -> "home" -> "somefolder" item and it's name is "myitem", the path is

```
/sitecore/content/home/somefolder/myitem
```

[image]